# ListView with buttons but only buttons are getting selected not the list

Tags: android, listview

I want to create an app in which I'm having a `ListView`.

I want my `ListView` to look like the below image. But the thing is that only the `Button`s in the list are clickable, nothing else. How can I achieve it

[image]

CustomList.Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#fff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Job Code"
                android:id="@+id/tv_job_code"
                style="@style/Job_on_Call"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Category"
                android:id="@+id/tv_category"
                style="@style/Job_on_Call"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="("
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                style="@style/Job_on_Call"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Years"
                android:id="@+id/tv_exp_yrs"
                style="@style/Job_on_Call"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=","
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                style="@style/Job_on_Call"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mnths"
                android:id="@+id/tv_exp_mnths"
                style="@style/Job_on_Call"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=")"
                android:id="@+id/textView45"
                style="@style/Job_on_Call"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Posted On:"
                style="@style/Job_on_Call"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="6-12-2014"
                android:id="@+id/tv_date"
                style="@style/Job_on_Call"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Matching Jobs"
                android:id="@+id/button"/>

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Applied Jobs"
                android:id="@+id/button2"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

CustomAdapter

```
package com.example.jobs_on_call_adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.jobs_on_call.app.R;
import com.example.jobs_on_call_object.SearchValues;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by ANUJ on 6/11/2014.
 */
public class SearchJobsCustomList extends BaseAdapter {
    Context c;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;

    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String> ();
    ArrayList<SearchValues> values;
    SearchValues a;

    public SearchJobsCustomList(Context c, ArrayList<SearchValues> values) {
        super ();
        this.c = c;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return values.size ();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        a = new SearchValues ();
        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from (c).inflate (R.layout.custom_search_jobs_lists, viewGroup, false);
            a = values.get (i);
            TextView JobCode = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_job_code);
            TextView Category = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_category);
            TextView ExpYrs = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_exp_yrs);
            TextView ExpMnths = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_exp_mnths);
            TextView Date = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_date);


            JobCode.setText (a.code);
            Category.setText (a.title);
//            ExpYrs.setText (resultp.get ("minExp"));
//            ExpMnths.setText (resultp.get ("maxExp"));
//            Date.setText (resultp.get ("postedOn"));


//            JobCode.setText ("CGT011");
//            Category.setText ("Press");
//            ExpYrs.setText ("1 Year");
//            ExpMnths.setText ("5 Months");
//            Date.setText ("6-6-14");


        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set an onItemClickListener on the ListView?

Comment: Can you show us the custom adapter ?

Comment: Just Set an onItemClickListener on the listview or implement the onItemClickListener interface in your activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android:focusable="false"` in your buttons properties in CustomList.Xml.
This should do the trick.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Matching Jobs"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:id="@+id/button"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Applied Jobs"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:id="@+id/button2"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Dont forget to add setOnItemClickListener in your listview.

Comment: yup it worked.But sir how to change the colour when the user selects the list, cos now no colour is showing

Comment: Use selectors to change the on click.

Comment: By the way you can accept this one and ask a new question regarding how to change the color.

Comment: when the user select particular list item listitem colour should chage to blue,but its not happening

Answer (score 2):

```
ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);  


listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                //Do your code here
            }
        });
```

Comment: i did but the list is not clickable:(

Answer (score 1):

```
    private class CustomList extends BaseAdapter
        {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
            public CustomList()
            {
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }

            public int getCount()
            {
                return arrItem.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position)
            {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position)
            {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView)
            {
                ViewHolder holder;
                if (convertView == null)
                {
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.Yourlayout, parentView, false);
                    holder.btn1=(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
                    holder.btn2=(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn2);

                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else
                {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }
            holder.btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    //apply your logic here.
                                 // you can get data here like. items.get(position);
                                   //items is custom Arraylist , ArrayList<Items> items=new ArrayList<Items>();
                }
            });
             holder.btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    //apply your logic here.
                }
            });
                     convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    //apply your logic here.
                }
            });
                return convertView;
            }

            class ViewHolder
            {
                Button btn1,btn2;
            }
        }
```

One of easy way... nJoy:)

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);  


lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                //here your logic
            }
        });
```

Comment: i tried doing like this but the list is not clickable nly
  @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Toast.makeText (c, "U selected" + i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the background of the item of your custom listview in its onclicklistener

```
yourlistview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            holder.yourlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`setOnItemClickListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) to detect clicks on ListView items.

Howerver, if you place *focusable* views on a `ListView`, then the ListView's OnItemClickListener will not fire. So you'll also need to set `android:focusable` and `android:focusableInTouchMode` to the `Button` widgets in the ListView item layout.